# Mac OS Lion System Preferences presenting a Modify Settings dialog over and over again

Tags: mac, osx-lion

After I installed OS X Lion, my System Preferences went crazy. When running it asks repeatedly for an admin password to modify permissions.

It happens especially frequently when I select the Mail, Contacts, and Calendar icon in System Preferences. It starts loading the different accounts and the permissions window pops up repeatedly, no matter whether I type the admin password in or hit cancel on every single one of them. When all the dialog boxes are closed, Preferences does eventually display all of my accounts.

Just while I was writing this question with System Preferences running in the background,  it has asked me for the administrative password four times.

I have checked the permissions and my volume.

[image: permission]
I dragged one of the dialog boxes from the huge stack of windows (top right). You can see that there are a lot of windows because of the darker shadow beneath the stack.

What might be causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting on multiple Stack Exchange sites in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me too. Fixed it by entering admin credentials in all (about 10) password prompts in succession.
Couldn't find any other way to fix it. I think it started behaving like this after installing iCloud beta.

Comment: yeah thats true, at one point it just topeed happening to me.. even without entering all the passwords, but yes its probaly som e icloud permissions problem, thanks still